# Not working shared hosting cPanel cronjob under Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cpanel, shared-hosting

Despite there are many posts with a similar topic, I couldn't find anyone matching my case that I briefly describe here. This is the testing script

```
    <?php

    if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    require 'DashboardBase.php';

    class Hello extends CI_Controller {

            public function message($to = 'World')
            {
                    echo "Hello {$to}!".PHP_EOL;
                    print "Hello {$to}!".PHP_EOL;
                    log_message('error',"Hello {$to}!".PHP_EOL);
            }
    }

    ?>
```

The web server is under a shared hosting; it is used cPanel; Codeigniter is used.

The external URL that works properly is this: https://pharmacomparison.com/adminPanel/hello/message/federico

I have activated the cronjob output notification on my personal email and it can be noted that I  also save the output in an error log.

Here my cronjob definition attempts

1. (as suggested by CodeIgniter manual): /usr/local/bin/php public_html/adminPanel hello message "federico" --> no email notification; no output in the 'error' log
2. small modification, added a "/": /usr/local/bin/php public_html/adminPanel/ hello message "federico" --> no email notification; no output in the 'error' log
3. (supposed wrong in advance, but let's try) /usr/local/bin/php public_html/adminPanel/hello message "federico" --> email notification reporting "Could not open input file: public_html/adminPanel/hello"; nothing in 'error' log
4. (supposed wrong in advance, but let's try) /usr/local/bin/php public_html/adminPanel/hello.php message "federico" --> no email notification, in 'error' log "ERROR - 2020-01-10 16:09:25 --> 404 Page Not Found: Hellophp/message"
5. full real disk path: notification email reporting "No direct script access allowed"

Basically, the first two attempts supposed correct generate nothing even no errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not running it correctly, [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html) is how to run a function in codeigniter through CLI.

Please try this

`php /usr/local/bin/php public_html/adminPanel/index.php Hello message "federico"`

All function calls must go through index.php

`php /path_to_project_root/index.php ControllerName function "argument"`

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but this generated an error notified by email: Warning: require(./vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/phar263d/public_html/adminPanel/index.php on line 66

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required './vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/phar263d/public_html/adminPanel/index.php on line 66

Comment: ok, I have personally not run any functions through CLI on shared hosting but l think it's not hitting the function through right path.

Comment: at least i have an error, but it seems to be related to the index.php file that should be something related to CodeIgniter framework.

Comment: are you sure your hosting provider allows you to run cronjobs ? because on most of the shared hosting they don't allow it.

Comment: of course if i run cronjobs outside codeigniter they work correctly. So the prblem is this: 1. when i run the controller for cronjobs calling it directly with the browser it works and the index.php recognize the path require './vendor/autoload.php'; 2. when the same controller is called by the cronjob that folder in the index.php is not recognized generating this error Warning: require(./vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: opened the consequent question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703413/require-vendor-autoload-php-failed-to-open-stream-error-just-if-it-is-run